# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate'), cannot navigate from component placed on screen to another screen

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation

im trying to navigate to another screen from component placed on HomePage, but the code below doesnt work. I think i tried all of the solutions that i found in the internet, but none of them seems to be working. (The button on HomePage is working)

HomePage:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,View ,Button} from 'react-native';
import RecipeButton from '../components/recipeButton';
import recipes from '../../assets/data/recipes';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

export default function HomePage({navigation}: {navigation: any}) {
  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <StatusBar style="light" backgroundColor="black" translucent={false} />
    <FlatList 
      style={{width:'100%'}}
      data={recipes}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <RecipeButton item={item} />}
    />
    <Button title='navigate to recipe' onPress={() => {
      navigation.navigate("Recipe")
    }} />
  </View>
  )
}
```

component script:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, View, Text, Pressable} from 'react-native';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import styles from './styles';

interface recipeButtonProps {
    item: {
        image: string,
    }
}


const RecipeButton = ({ item }: recipeButtonProps, {navigation}: {navigation: any}) => {

    const onPress = () => {
        navigation.navigate("Recipe")
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.root}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: item.image }} />

            <Pressable
             style={({pressed}) => [
                {backgroundColor: pressed ? '#D3D3D3' : 'white'},
                styles.nonImageContainer
            ]} 
            onPress={() => {
                onPress();
            }}>
            </Pressable>
        </View>
    );
};

export default RecipeButton;
```

Comment: Try passing down the navigation property like `<FlatList 
      style={{width:'100%'}}
      data={recipes}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <RecipeButton item={item} navigation={navigation} />}
    />`

Comment: it doesnt work 
                                
Type '{ item: { id: string; user: { id: string; name: string; image: string; }; name: string; image: string; recipe: string; required: string; rating: number; ratingsCount: number; neededTime: string; difficulty: string; }; navigation: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & recipeButtonProps'.
  Property 'navigation' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & recipeButtonProps'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `RecipeButton` is not in the context of the navigator, so it doesn't get the `navigation` prop.

Try to use the `useNavigation()` hook like this:

```
...
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
...


const RecipeButton = ({ item }: recipeButtonProps) => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    
    const onPress = () => {
        navigation.navigate("Recipe")
    }

    ...
};

export default RecipeButton;
```